# How to initialize a List<List<T>> in Kotlin

Tags: android, list, kotlin, initialization

How do I initialize a List of Lists type T in Kotlin?

I need to init the List with an initial capacity and then add lists dynamically later. Something like:

```
class something(numLists: Int, startPos: Int)
{
var myList: List<List<T>>

init{
myList = // init list with emptyLists to the capacity of numLists
myList[startPos] = listOf<T> // Init one list at startPos
}

/// code...

myList[anotherPosition] = listOf<T>
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First I suggest you change to a `MutableList` since you want to change the contents of your list.

Finally you can call a function in `MutableList` to achieve that.

Something like this:

```
class something<T>(numLists: Int, startPos: Int) {
    var myList: MutableList<MutableList<T>>

    init {
        myList = MutableList(numLists) {mutableListOf<T>()}
    }
```

Comment: This isn't the constructor, just a method called `MutableList` (`MutableList` is an interface, it can't have a constructor).

Comment: My bad. I will fix it :)